# Bootstrap modal don't scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

On click I close first modal (data-dismiss="modal") and I open another modal. First modal it scoll but second modal not.

```
<button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-edit-modal-sm" 
style="margin:6.18px;">edit</button>
```

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: I changed bootstrap .modal to position:fixed;
overflow:scroll; and is ok now.